# How to display a json object as plain text with no brackets

Tags: node.js, express, stringify

Here I am getting a column from a database as a javascript object.  I am then trying to get the contents from the object as a string via stringify and am rendering it to my ejs page.  The contents from the data base are in a json format  {"con":.  How to i get the contents from the column to display as plain text?

```
var table= require('../models/table');

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    table.where({ id:1 })
        .fetch({ columns: ['con'] })
        .then(function(model){
            str = JSON.stringify(model);
            res.render('page.ejs', { str });
        });
});
```

Comment: check out the native method JSON.parse

Comment: Can't really suggest a solution without understanding the contents and the format you're trying to display it in. By using stringify the object is technically rendered as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to remove `[]{}` characters: `str.replace(/[\[\]\{\}]+/g, '')`.

You can continue to escape other characters such as quotes if that's what you're looking for.